# What is the best alternative of java Array List in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to implement json array list but in flutter no array list is avail is there any alternative of array list in Dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally `List`. Check out [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List-class.html) the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple List in flutter https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html

`List<String> myList = List<String>();`